# apt-get install git-core failed

Tags: command-line, apt, 10.04, dpkg, git

After running `sudo apt-get install git-core`, I get

```
Unpacking git-core (from .../git-core_1%3a1.7.4.1-3_all.deb) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/git_1%3a1.7.4.1-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I followed the instructions from [Error Installing Git with Apt-Get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100612/error-installing-git-with-apt-get) but that didn't work either.

I encountered this after running `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq git`:

```
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `git' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `git-man' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `git-core' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 79719 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing git ...
```

At some point I was asked to run `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix things but it's saying its going to install git

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  git
Suggested packages:
  git-doc git-el git-arch git-cvs git-svn git-email git-daemon-run git-gui gitk gitweb
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 480 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4,658kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.9MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

And after clicking yes, the error occurs again:

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ natty/main git 1:1.7.4.1-3 [4,658kB]
Fetched 4,658kB in 5s (907kB/s)
Selecting previously deselected package git.
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `git-man' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.

dpkg: warning: files list file for package `git-core' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 79719 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking git (from .../git_1%3a1.7.4.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 12: dpkg-maintscript-helper: not found
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/git_1%3a1.7.4.1-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: 14: dpkg-maintscript-helper: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/git_1%3a1.7.4.1-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

For some reasons, when I do `dpgk --get-selections | grep git`, I get:

```
git                                             install
git-core                                        install
git-man                                         install
```

So I'm stuck in this cycle. How can I fix it?

On Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Comment: try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` from your terminal

Comment: `files list file for package 'git-core' missing` makes me shiver. Somehow the DPKG database (in this case it's either the list of files or the packages status) has become corrupted. This does not occur by itself and I think you're looking at a glitch in the direction of disk corruption, unclean killed apt/dpkg operations, manual edit to the `/var/lib/dpkg` directory, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but a team  member solved the problem for me. not exactly sure what he did, but I believe he removed the package and reinstall through lucid repo instead of nutty which he said it was on previously.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, works for me most of the time

```
$ sudo apt-get remove git-core
$ sudo apt-get autoremove

$ cd /var/cache/apt/archives
```

and remove the git file that gives problem with adminstrator privileges.

```
$ rm git_1%3a1.7.4.1-3_amd64.deb
```

or the corresponding file.

then run

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
```

If still problem persists, try removing all the files in the /var/cache/apt/archives by

```
$ sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*
```

and then run

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
```